# Express.js: Execution doesn't stop after error handler. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've written an express app to create a REST API.

As I understand this, if I send a header with an invalid token, jwt.verify sets err (JsonWebTokenError), which is passed to my error handler and it sends a 401:

```
res.status(401).send({
        success: false,
        message: err.name
});
```

And execution should end. But instead, I get this:

```
Start token verification
Error before: JsonWebTokenError
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
at Object.module.exports.verify (/srv/lonja/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:129:17)
at /srv/lonja/app/routes/api.js:76:17
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
at trim_prefix (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
at /srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
at Function.proto.process_params (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
at next (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
at Function.proto.handle (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:3)
at router (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:35:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
This is the last message related to[object Object]
GET /api/home_gallery/ 401 20.834 ms - 47
_http_outgoing.js:335
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/srv/lonja/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:240:15)
at /srv/lonja/app/routes/api.js:214:17
at /srv/lonja/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:103:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

So, after the error handling, the route handler is executed, and I don't understand why.

My code (just the relevant bits):

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var myImage = require('../models/image');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('../../config');

// super secret for creating tokens
var superSecret = config.secret;

module.exports = function(app, express) {

    var apiRouter = express.Router();
```

I use this piece of middleware to verify a jsonwebtoken:

```
   // route middleware to verify a token
apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Start token verification');

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.params.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            else req.decoded = decoded;
        });
    }
    // if there is no token
    // return an HTTP response of 401 (access unauthorized) and an error message
    else {
        var noToken = new Error('Error_NoTokenProvided');
        return next(noToken);
    }
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});
```

Later in the code, I've got this route handler:

```
apiRouter.route('/home_gallery')
// get all the images
.get(function(req, res) {
    myImage.find(function(err, images) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        // return the users
        res.json(images);
    });
});
```

And finally, this last piece of middleware to do the error handling:

```
apiRouter.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('Error before: ' + err.name);
    if (err.name == 'Error_NoTokenProvided' ||
        err.name == 'JsonWebTokenError') {
        res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.name
        });
    } else if (err.name == 'TokenExpiredError') {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.name
        });
    }
    console.log(err.stack);
    console.log('This is the last message related to' + req);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be this:

```
if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        else req.decoded = decoded;
    });
} else { ... }
next();
```

Since `jwt.verify()` is an asychronous method, processing continues after that function call, which means that the bottom `next()` is called. If the token verification fails, you call `next(err)`; in other words, you call `next()` twice.

One possible solution would be:

```
if (token) {
    // We use `return` only to stop further processing of the middleware,
    // we don't actually care about the return value from `jwt.verify()`.
    return jwt.verify(token, superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        else {
          req.decoded = decoded;
          next();
        }
    });
}
```

Something similar is happening in your route handler:

```
if (err) res.send(err);
// return the users
res.json(images);
```

If `err` is set, you call both `res.send()` and `res.json()`, because calling `res.send()` doesn't miraculously stop further processing of the rest of the code.

A similar solution as above can be used:

```
if (err) return res.send(err);
res.json(images);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
if (err) {
  res.send(err);
} else {
  res.json(images);
}
```

Comment: I've been thinking about this and I have a doubt, aren't we converting the code in syncronous doing all these `if else` statements. The execution has to wait for the _asyncronous_ call in order to be able to continue execution, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @mvillar the async function here is `jwt.verify()`, and we're waiting for that to complete before `next()` is called (it's being called in the completion callback to `jwt.verify()`). The `if/else` is only to distinguish which call to `next()` to make.